# Find at which iteration function got its max value?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, transliteration

Imagine i have following while loop. while i reachs to 6, it  generates random numbers from -100 to i.
I want to find maximum number out of 5 iteration. My default max number is -99. in each iteration it compares generated value with -99. if it is greater than -99 i replace it, otherwise i keep -99 as max numver. With following piece of code i can find it
But i also want to find in which iteration it got its maximum value:

```
import random
m=-99
i=1
k=0
while i<6:
    a = random.randint(-100,i)
    b = random.randint(-100,i+1)
    print("a: ", a)
    print("b: ", b)
    if a < b & b>m:
        m=b
        print('1st', i)
    elif a < b & b<m:
        m=m
        print('2nd', i)
    elif a > b & a>m:
        m=a
        print('3rd', i)
    elif a > b & a<m:
        m=m
        print('4th', i)
    print('m: ', m)
    print('--------')
    i = i+1


a:  -77
b:  -34
1st 1
m:  -34
--------
a:  -44
b:  -45
4th 2
m:  -34
--------
a:  -24
b:  2
1st 3
m:  2
--------
a:  -18
b:  -43
4th 4
m:  2
--------
a:  -80
b:  -37
2nd 5
m:  2
--------
```

As u see from output, out of 5 iteration max number is "2". which i got in 3rd iteration
How can i find it? I see it manually, But how can i add line of codes which also gives me the muber of iteration i which it gets "2" which is max number.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a variable `pos`, which describes the first place that the maximum value or the value of the variable `m` has increased. So your code will probably be something like this:

```
import random
m=-99
i=1
pos=-1
k=0
while i<6:
    a = random.randint(-100,i)
    b = random.randint(-100,i+1)
    print("a: ", a)
    print("b: ", b)
    if a < b & b>m:
        pos=i
        m=b
        print('1st', i)
    elif a < b & b<m:
        m=m
        print('2nd', i)
    elif a > b & a>m:
        pos=i
        m=a
        print('3rd', i)
    elif a > b & a<m:
        m=m
        print('4th', i)
    print('m: ', m)
    print('--------')
    i = i+1
print(pos)
```

Comment: why you wrote  `pos=i` only in first and 4th condition?

Comment: Because only in those conditions the max value changes. If the max value doesn't change in an iteration, it means that the value currently found is equal or less than the maximum so far. so we don't need to update `pos` in those conditions.

Comment: i see. Thanks, i understand!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable `max_iter` to track which iteration got the max. It gets updated every time the `m`'s value gets updated to have current iteration.

```
import random
m=-99
max_iter=0
i=1
k=0
while i<6:
    a = random.randint(-100,i)
    b = random.randint(-100,i+1)
    print("a: ", a)
    print("b: ", b)
    if a < b & b>m:
        m=b
        max_iter=i
        print('1st', i)
    elif a < b & b<m:
        m=m
        print('2nd', i)
    elif a > b & a>m:
        m=a
        max_iter=a
        print('3rd', i)
    elif a > b & a<m:
        m=m
        print('4th', i)
    print('m: ', m)
    print('--------')
    i = i+1
print(max_iter)
```